# Computer froze when installing Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I was installing Ubuntu on my Windows 7 laptop (creating a dual boot) and the wifi doesn't work on the laptop so I had to plug it in on the slower connection, and when it was trying to download the language packs it froze and has now been frozen for almost half an hour! What should I do? Any help appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Windows turns of the wifi card  when it's shut down. When you start Ubuntu you have to toggle the wifi card (there should be a button or switch) and then reboot.  Also, make sure that "enable wireless" has a check next to it in the drop down menu from the icon in the top left. That should take care of the wifi issue.

Which version of Ubuntu are you trying to install? I noticed on 11.10 that everything went way smoother if I didn't select for additional drivers and updates to be installed during the OS's installation. So, try a plain install and add everything else after the update once you first boot.

Comment: Well actually the problem is that the wifi card broke so no matter what it won't work, I didn't select update well installs and yes it is 11.10

Answer (score -1):

If you were installing to a new partition: start again. (i.e. try ctrl-alt-del, or, worst case, turn it off on the switch and turn it back on again.) There's no damage in it, and it's the simplest way to make sure that you end up with a full and complete install.

If it crashes again, however, the problem might be a bit more serious and we'll try and sort it out.

Comment: I shut it off and booted of e flash drive just fine, but it froze up when it tried to partition the hard drive. Tried to repboot to in to windows. But it started windows recovery

Comment: The windows side got fixed, I am gonna look at the hard rive cause the second time I tried to install Ubuntu. There was 30gb less on the hard drive

Comment: It does sound like the problem is a little bit more serious; is this your first time installing Ubuntu? If not, or you're fairly experienced, you can use the 'alternative install' cd which will show any errors a little more clearly.

Comment: Also, the loss of space is believable; it's probably where the installer allocated space on the first unsuccessful attempt; you can spot the partitions made by ubuntu because they will be ext4 file types (if you used the defaults,) and can be safely deleted if this is your first time trying ubuntu (i.e. you're not upgrading and need to protect old ubuntu data.)